# How do I model a 3-table database in a ASP.NET web app using Razor Pages?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework-core, multiple-tables, razor-pages

Creating my first web app. Using `ASP.NET` and `Razor Pages`**+**. Developing it in VS 2017.

(Note: Similar to unanswered S.O. question [ASP.NET Core : Generate Razor Pages for all models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50894240/asp-net-core-generate-razor-pages-for-all-models))

*+In ASP.NET Core tutorials [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/?view=aspnetcore-2.1] it says this: "Razor Pages is the recommended approach to create a new Web UI app with ASP.NET Core 2.0."*

First thing I did was create my database using `SSMS`:

[image]

Then, I created a `ASP.NET Core Web Application`

[image]

Then, I created a model from the existing database (Used only the `Reverse engineer your model` step of [Getting Started with EF Core on ASP.NET Core with an Existing Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db)

[image]

Then, I used the `Scaffold the movie model` step of [Add a model to a Razor Pages app in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

[image]

The scaffolding step requires that you choose one class from the Models folder and produces generically-named CRUD pages in (my case) the Pages\keyw_status folder.

If I scaffold the 2nd and 3rd classes from my model, the generically-named CRUD pages in the Pages\keyw_status folder will be overwritten. Last model class scaffolded wins, right?

How do I scaffold a 3-table model using `Razor Pages`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the folder for the scaffolded pages using the `-outDir` option to ensure that the CRUD pages for each entity are generated in different folder. Usually, people pick the name of the entity for the folder, because that becomes your URL.

The following command will scaffold CRUD pages for the `DateTable` entity, and place them in *Pages\DataTable*.

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator razorpage -m DateTable -dc keyw_statusContext -udl -outDir Pages\DateTable
```